# Facebook HTML5 Content inside an post

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i was very happy if facebook allow developer to put HTML5 content inside/attached an POST.
But as i know, is not possibile.

Today, i just discover that an App do that very fine and i want to ask you how is possibile.

[image: AppTracker]

As you can see, this is an Facebook Post Wall, and this "widget" is very amazing!

How is possibile to make this widget?

Answer (score 1):

That's not "normal" HTML5 content. Those apps make use of specific OpenGraph stories, which Facebook renders depending on their type.

Have a look at the according OpenGraph docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.bikes/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.runs/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/fitness.walks/

Comment: so, do you think that is not possible to embed 'custom' HTML5 content? Example, i want to make an 'html5' video player instead of using YouTube video player. Is possibile?

Comment: I have see that SoundCloud make it happen:

https://soundcloud.com/ricardomaranhao/pull-the-trigger

Try to share on YouTube; have you any idea how is possibile?